# Error in react event handler is fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If error happens in react event handler (onChange in this case) it is displayed two times in console. Is it correct? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

`onChange` handler is called once.

I am going to setup monitoring on my page and do not want to have duplicated error.

Tested in react v16.

https://codesandbox.io/s/480y71xo00

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: '' };
  }

  onChange(event){
    console.log('Call unknown function once');
    //!!!
    what();

    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render(){
    const {text} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If you type something in input:

In Chrome
[image]

But in Safari errors look like this:
[image]

Comment: Notice how you got the same exception but from two different files? I believe it is only firing once, but you are seeing two exceptions of the same type in two different file locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is intended, this is explained in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10384 and discussed here : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10474

Here's the explanation from Dan Abramov :

> For context, the reason it happens is because we intentionally let the
>   browser interpret an error as uncaught before we rethrow. The
>   justification is discussed in #10474.
>
> If you follow the advice in the error and add an error boundary (which
>   you should!), you will only see the error once. So that's not a huge
>   problem in day-to-day workflow. In fact it nudges people to add error
>   boundaries which is nice.
>
> Another justification for this is that if you accidentally swallow an
>   error we still print it once. That alone makes this worth it IMO.
>   We’ve had hundreds of comments and dozens of issues caused by people
>   swallowing their own errors, and the fact that we will print them at
>   least once now seems like enough benefit to compensate for printing
>   them twice when they’re uncaught, un-swallowed, and don’t have a
>   boundary.